# How to merge DLL for C++ Application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dllexport, ilmerge

I have created dll project in visual studio 2022 and developed DataDecryption.dll that decrypt data using AES 256, but there are some dependency dll along with that like libcurl.dll and zlib1.dll , how can I merge these dependent dll in one ? I have tried ILMerger but It didnt work?

Can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: ***how can I merge these dependent dll in one?*** Most likely this is very difficult and may take you weeks of work to accomplish. It's far easier to just do what most commercial software does and create an installer for your application.

Comment: Site usage note: Rather than writing "It didn't work" or any of its many variants, describe what happened, diagnostic messages, behaviour, etc.... It doesn't work conveys no information, and that is often the kiss of death in a question.

Comment: Are you using .net? The tag says that "ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly." Which really does not seem to say it has anything to do with native standard c++ which you tagged. libcurl.dll and zlib1.dll are not net assemblies.

Comment: Don't start with DLLs.  All the libraries you name are easily available as static libraries.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.